# WPF ToolTip containing buttons can not recieve Mouse events, alternative?

Tags: wpf, tooltip

I want a formatbar like in Office 2010 with WPF:

- Select Text and then click buttons on appearing tooltip to execute a command

How can I make that work?

Answer (score 3):

The ToolTip window can't accept focus, use the [Popup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.aspx) control instead. It's a bit more cumbersome, than a tooltip, because many useful properties are set to false by default, here is a tiny example:

```
<Popup x:Name="samplePopup" PopupAnimation="Fade" Placement="Mouse" AllowsTransparency="True" StaysOpen="False" >
      <Popup.Child>
         <StackPanel Margin="10" >
                <TextBlock Text="Some Text" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />

                <Button Content="Close" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
         </StackPanel>
      </Popup.Child>
</Popup>
```

Comment: How do you determine if the mouse is over selected text so you can set IsOpen on the popup?