# WPF ToolTip: Is there any option to Click on a Button that is inside tooltip (code and picture attached)

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, wpf, visual-studio

I am facing this problem:

[image: Visual explanation]
code:

```
<Grid>   
    <Button Content="Submit" Width="100" Height="100" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Button.ToolTip>
            <ToolTip Placement="MousePoint" StaysOpen="True" IsOpen="False" >
                <StackPanel Background="BlueViolet">
                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold">Submit Request</TextBlock>
                     <Button Name="btn2" Content="ClickMe" Margin="10" Click="btnRefresh_Click"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </ToolTip>
        </Button.ToolTip>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

I also read this question 
[WPF ToolTip containing buttons can not recieve Mouse events, alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444273/wpf-tooltip-containing-buttons-can-not-recieve-mouse-events-alternative)
Is there any workaround?

Comment: In accord with [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/bef8d64f-0fb2-4e8e-bc58-20637dd0aecf/clickable-tooltip?forum=wpf) answer you cannot use tooptip for you purposes. The best workaround is to use Popup and it is posted in question you attached

Comment: Thanks, I was tring to avoid using popup - Last resort

Comment: Why don't you want to use popup?

Comment: Because I will be need to render its location manually each time (size/location/visibility  of the user control changed)

Comment: No, please view answer posted. You can just say Placement="Mouse"

Comment: Yes, but i don't want that the popup will be where the mouse is.I need the button (the popup will contain a button) on a special location (x,y) on the Usercontrol. and this usercontrol is going to be drag and the size changed but the popup will remain at it "starting" point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Popup` instead of `ToolTip`:

```
<Button Content="Open Tooltip" Width="120" Height="40" MouseEnter="ShowTooltip"/>
<Popup PopupAnimation="Fade" Placement="Mouse" AllowsTransparency="True" StaysOpen="False" x:Name="TooltipPopup" >
  <Border Background="AntiqueWhite" BorderBrush="Bisque" CornerRadius="3" BorderThickness="1">
    <StackPanel Margin="10" Orientation="Horizontal" >
      <Button Content="Update" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Click="UpdateTime" />
      <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" x:Name="TestClickTarget" Margin="20 0 0 0" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </StackPanel>
  </Border>
</Popup>
```

And in code-behind you'll have this (as an example):

```
// opens the popup
// you can bind set TooltipPopup.IsOpen in any event you want (e.g. MouseEnter, Click, etc.
private void ShowTooltip(object sender, MouseEventArgs e){
    TooltipPopup.IsOpen = true;
}

// doing something, when the Button in popup got clicked:
private void UpdateTime(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
    TestClickTarget.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("T");
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Working with a `TextBox`:

**XAML** (`MainWindow.xaml`):

```
<Window x:Class="ClickableTooltip.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <Grid>
    <TextBox MaxLines="10" MinLines="2" Height="100" Width="400" SelectionChanged="ShowTextTooltip" x:Name="Box">
    </TextBox>
    <Popup PopupAnimation="Fade" Placement="Mouse" AllowsTransparency="True" StaysOpen="False" x:Name="TooltipPopup" >
      <Border Background="AntiqueWhite" BorderBrush="Bisque" CornerRadius="3" BorderThickness="1"
              MinHeight="40" MaxHeight="100" MinWidth="200" MaxWidth="400">
        <StackPanel Margin="10" Orientation="Horizontal" >
          <Button Content="Update" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Click="UpdateTime" />
          <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" x:Name="TestClickTarget" Margin="20 0 0 0" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </StackPanel>
      </Border>
    </Popup>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

**C#** (`MainWindow.xaml.cs`):

```
public partial class MainWindow {
    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
        TestClickTarget.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("T");
        Box.AppendText("Hello SO users. I'm Javad Amiry." + Environment.NewLine);
        Box.AppendText("Hello SO users. I'm Javad Amiry in second line." + Environment.NewLine);
        Box.AppendText("Hello SO users. I'm Javad Amiry in third line ;)" + Environment.NewLine);
        Box.AppendText("And \"Hello SO users. I'm Javad Amiry.\" the last one :D" + Environment.NewLine);
    }

    private void ShowTextTooltip(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        var box = e.OriginalSource as TextBox;
        if (box == null || TestClickTarget == null)
            return;
        TestClickTarget.Text = box.SelectedText;
        TooltipPopup.IsOpen = box.SelectionLength != 0;
    }

    private void UpdateTime(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        TestClickTarget.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("T");
    }
}
```

Comment: The only thing that works strangely...when button is clicked, popup does not appear anymore

Comment: Cause popup is bounded to window.mousedown every where but self. You should handle the click event on button, if you want to open popup by that event

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to avoid using popup .I will need that the popup will be on a special location (x,y) on the User control (Placement = {Binding ..}). This user control is going to be drag and the size changed/Visibility. But the popup will remain at it "starting" point unless i will render it manually.